# Postgres: Get aggregation query based on multiple values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have following database table:

```
id, owner_id, partner_id, level
1, 121, 234, gold
2, 121, 342, silver
3, 121, 423, silver
4, 233, 333, silver
5, 233, 434, gold
```

I am trying to get result in following format:

```
owner_id, number_of_partners, total_gold, total_silver, total_bronze
```

I am not sure if this is possible to do, I so far I started with the basic group by query where I get the total partners per owner.

```
SELECT owner_id, count(partner_id) FROM owner_partner GROUP BY owner_id
```

How can I extend this to get my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT owner_id, count(partner_id),
       sum(case when level = 'gold' then 1 else 0 end) as gold,
       sum(case when level = 'silver' then 1 else 0 end) as silver,
       sum(case when level = 'bronze' then 1 else 0 end) as bronze
FROM owner_partner
GROUP BY owner_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest shorter syntax (about same performance as `CASE` statements):

```
SELECT owner_id
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(level = 'gold' OR NULL) AS gold
     , count(level = 'silver' OR NULL) AS silver
     , count(level = 'bronze' OR NULL) AS bronze
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```